# Android animation not working in BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-animation

i am trying to use Pulsator4Droid.
https://github.com/booncol/Pulsator4Droid

It works outside of a BaseAdapter, although inside the adapter it does not work.
I have tried it in multiple basic BaseAdapters and none of them work, although XML animations do...  Any ideas why this might be happening?

home_menu_grid_pulse_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <pl.bclogic.pulsator4droid.library.PulsatorLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/pulsator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:pulse_count="4"
        app:pulse_duration="7000"
        app:pulse_repeat="0"
        app:pulse_color="#FF0000"
        app:pulse_interpolator="Linear"
        app:pulse_startFromScratch="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"> 

    </pl.bclogic.pulsator4droid.library.PulsatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

HomeMenuGridAdapter.java :

```
package com.au.test.helpers.common;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.au.test.R;
import java.util.List;
import pl.bclogic.pulsator4droid.library.PulsatorLayout;

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
public class HomeMenuGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Activity context;
    private List<HomeMenuItem> array = null;

    public HomeMenuGridAdapter(Context mContext, List<HomeMenuItem> _list) {
        context = (Activity) mContext;
        array = _list;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return array.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return array.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_menu_grid_pulse_item, null);
        }

        // Get Controls 
        PulsatorLayout pulsator = (PulsatorLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pulsator);  
        pulsator.start();

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code and the error please?

Comment: show your adapter code.

Comment: Hi guys, there is no error, it just doesn't show the animation.   I'll edit my question and share my code

Comment: yes this gives more clear vision. so you want to animate PulsatorLayout right?

Comment: That's correct.  The red pulsing works when it's not in an Adapter, although it doesn't work when it is in an Adapter.

Comment: @Nickmccomb check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the width and height of the XML view.

Programatically setting the width and heigh doesn't work with pulseView.setIconHeight(200) and pulseView.setIconWidth(200), neither does wrap_content or match_parent on the View (even when the parent is full screen :/), i had to hard-code an actual size..

I made my View's height and width 200px and it works... Not very elegant but it's good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

modify your getView method like following. you should use `setTag` and `getTag` approach to achieve this.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    if (null == convertView) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_menu_grid_pulse_item, null);
    }

    // Get Controls 
    PulsatorLayout pulsator = (PulsatorLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pulsator);  
    pulsator.start();

   //set tag on converview with your key
    convertView.setTag("yourKEY");
    return convertView;
}
```

to get that access of this control outside of adapter you need to use `getTag` like following in your activity.

```
View v = yourcontrolobject.findViewWithTag("yourKEY");
                if (v != null) {
                    PulsatorLayout obj= (PulsatorLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.pulsator);

// do whatever you wnat to do now with this obj.

                }
```

Comment: Hi Chirayu, this doesn't solve the problem of the View not animating, it just moves the reference to the view outside of the Adapter Class.. which isn't what i was after (and is bad for IOC & unit testing etc)

Comment: @Nickmccomb this approach works perfectly for me. it gives you exact position value to animate your control. may be you are right unit testing. i dont know much about it. but this scenario worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your Adapter class, it's working properly...
[Have a look at this](http://prntscr.com/db5drv)

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;

public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 10;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(view == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_file, viewGroup, false);

        viewHolder.pulsator = (PulsatorLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pulsator);
        viewHolder.tvCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_count);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.pulsator.start();
    viewHolder.tvCount.setText("My listview row No-> " + i);
    return view;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    PulsatorLayout pulsator;
    TextView tvCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bhavnik, i initially tried the ViewHolder pattern and it didn't work, the View is still not animating :(

I will try Devlight, as you suggested, and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Did you change your getView() method of adapter ???? Because It is working properly , I've attached screenshot of demo